# angular.runNgcc not found in VS Code

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, angular-language-service

I've just installed vs code and I've added the Angular Language service extension but it is not working.

It does not run ngcc at the vs code load of an angular project.

When I try to run this manually I have this error:

[image]

Any ideas of how can I solve this?

edit:

This is the current package.json

```
{
  "name": "myapp-front",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^14.0.0",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^14.3.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^14.3.0",
    "primeflex": "^3.2.1",
    "primeicons": "^5.0.0",
    "primeng": "^14.0.2",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.2.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~14.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.3.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.8.2"
  }
}
```

After followed @debugger instructions It launched but I now get this error in the output console for that extension:

[Error - 7:52:24 PM] No config file for /home/dmance/development/myapp/myapp-front/src/app/domain/cars/pages/create-car/create-car.component.html

Comment: can you provide your `package.json` file?

Comment: hey @debugger thanks for your reply, i've just added my package.json to the question

Comment: in your script change `"ng": "ng"` to `"ng": "ngcc"`  then try `npm run ng`

Comment: Or you can try clean install project [npm ci](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-ci)

Comment: hey debugger, it worked fine, but now i got another error in the output console

Comment: what error you are getting ?

Comment: Thise [Error - 7:52:24 PM] No config file for /home/dmance/development/myapp/myapp-front/src/app/domain/cars/pages/create-car/create-car.component.html

Comment: @dmance any chance you figured this one out? I have the same issue with the angular language service extension

Comment: @m_bale I think I solved it reinstalling all the node_modules package... but i do not remember well